# Can I use an expression as an array index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, google-apps-script, expression

Ok folks, I am trying to copy a section of a large array into an array of objects. The large array is a row from a google sheet which represents RMA data. The small array contains several (circuit) board objects. I am reading 4 items from the large array into each 'board'. To read the correct item from the large array, I need to increment the operator before reading into a new named property in my object within my small array. If I was using an array for 'board' it would be easy: create a sub loop and increment the index at each iteration. But because I'm using an object, I don't know how to do it. I tried to use an expression in my index (see code). Also, btw all this is happening inside a larger object designed to read in multiple rows from a google sheet and process them. Here's the code:

```
board:
           [
           {
           code: "Board Code",
           software: "S-Ver",
           problem: "Problem",
           riu: "RiU",
           msqNotes: "MSq Notes"
           }
           ],
grab: function (rowArray, board)
          {
          rma.timestamp = rowArray[1];
          rma.guidelinesAgree = rowArray[2];
          rma.expediteyn = rowArray[3];
          rma.contact.name = rowArray[4];
          rma.contact.coName = rowArray[5];
          rma.contact.emailAddr = rowArray[6];
          rma.contact.telNum = rowArray[7];
          rma.contact.shipAddr = rowArray[8];
          var boardArray = rma.createBoardArray();
          var boardStartIndex = 9;
          for(i = 0; i< 5; i++)
            {
            var k = i + 1;
            board.push()
            board[k].code = rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4i]; //prob here
            board[k].software = rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4i + 1];
            board[k].problem = rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4i + 2];
            board[k].riu = rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4i + 3];
            board[k].msqNotes = "";
            }
```

Note: In Google script editor, when I try to debug, I get the error: "Missing ] in index expression." at the line that I've labeled "//prob here" above.

Another Note: I am using an expression 'k' for the index, because I have purposely initialized the 'board' array with a board[0] that contains title values.... I want to create a google doc afterword with a table that has the first row full of titles/labels for each column, and I am using the first object to store those titles. Previously I was using "board[i+1].code =" etc.

IS THERE A WAY TO USE AN EXPRESSION FOR AN ARRAY INDEX THAT IS KOSHER IN JS?

Comment: what means `4i`? it is not a valid identifier.

Comment: "i" is the loop [increment] variable - see the 'for' statement.

Comment: You probably mean `4*i`. You can use any arbitrary expression as an array index as long as that expression results in a number. Also `board.push()` isn't doing anything. Maybe you meant `board.push({})`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error:

```
rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4i]
```

I'm guessing you meant this:

```
rowArray[boardStartIndex + 4 * i]
```

I know in math & science "4i" means "4 times i" but in Javascript you have to use the "*" operator.

Comment: *facepalm*... Thank you so much!